# Linespacing in algpseudocode

Tags: algorithms

I would like to add a 1.5 vertical linespacing after several lines of pseudocode. This is just for better readability and the spacing should not have its own linenumber. How would you do this?

I am using `algpseudocode`, but I am still confused by the different algorithm packages. I basically took `algpseudocode` because it produces right aligned comments with a nice triangle symbol.

Comment: Can you not just use a `\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}` or `\\[1.5\baselineskip]`? Or would you like this as the new default?

Comment: This does work. Thanks. Never used commands like this, because it migth break other things.

Comment: Used properly there doesn't seem any obvious caveats to using them, although without an example it is hard to determine if you're correctly/appropriately using or misusing them.